# Using Regex to match word with dash

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<div id="cr__init-8f5a1fce"></div>
```

I need to be able to isolate the id by using cr__.  I've tried  `\b\w*cr__\b` but that's not working. I'm new to regex so I'm certain I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not clear as what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to extract value of `id` attribute?

Comment: Your regex won't match as there is `i` after `__` in the text which is not a word bounday so you need to get rid of `\b` at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the full id you can use something like `(?<=id=").*(?=">)`

Which will return `cr__init-8f5a1fce`

Or if you just want the part after the `cr__` then: `(?<=cr__).*(?=">)`, which gives `init-8f5a1fce`